# Spacing issues with grid container -> item -> container -> item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm giving material-ui a try and I'm making a responsive address component. I am having to tweak the padding and margins a bit to get everything aligned properly, and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Here is what my view looks like:

[image: Pickup details]

The red arrows point to the extra padding between state/zip and city. This only occurs at smaller sizes (sm, xs).

Here's what the fix looks like. I've included inline styles to show that needs to be adjusted in order to correct the padding.

```
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <Typography type="title">Address</Typography>
          <TextField label="Street" fullWidth />
          <TextField label="Street 2" fullWidth />

        <Grid container style={{ marginTop: 0}}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6} style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
            <TextField label="City" fullWidth />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
            <TextField label="State" fullWidth />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md style={{paddingTop: 0}}>
            <TextField label="Zip" fullWidth/>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
        <Typography type="title">Point of contact</Typography>
        <TextField label="Name" fullWidth />
        <TextField label="Phone number" fullWidth />
        <TextField label="Special instrucitons" fullWidth multiline />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Maybe I'm misusing the grid component? I'm not sure.

Here's a `codesandbox` example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wnqqyljxw7

(if you remove the inline styles and adjust the page size, you can see extra space adding to the state/zip in this example.

Comment: fyi, it's good to pin versions in package.json, so that codesandboxes continue working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some minor issues with your JSX. If you want 2 columns on a small-medium-sized screen, then make your outer container so the direction is 'row' (<Grid container direction={'row'}>). If you want it to stack, give that outer container's direction attribute a value of 'column'.

Nest your labels and text fields in  components so their height/width are calculated consistently, and so the items predictably stack on one another. You can add alignItems or justify attributes as well, but these are optional. You've left-aligned everything, so I suggest 'flex-start' as a starting value for justify and alignItems.

Be consistent with your screen-size break-points as well. Some items have breakpoints at xs and md, but the rest have breakpoints for xs and sm, with an unspecified value for md. Maybe that's syntax that MUI allows, although I've never seen it. I always add explicit values for my breakpoints. If you want the columns to occupy 50% of the parent container's width for small and medium screens, you should only have to specify a value for sm. You can specify another value for large screens, maybe 25-33% (lg={3} or lg={4}).

And do take a look at MUI's documentation: https://material-ui.com/components/grid/

Try this:

```
<Grid container direction={'row'}>
 <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
  <Typography type="title">Address</Typography>
  <TextField label="Street" fullWidth />
  <TextField label="Street 2" fullWidth />

  <Grid container direction={'row'} alignItems={'stretch'}>
   <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <TextField label="City" fullWidth />
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <TextField label="State" fullWidth />
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <TextField label="Zip" fullWidth/>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    Placeholder
   </Grid>
  </Grid>
 </Grid>

 <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
  <Typography type="title">Point of contact</Typography>
  <TextField label="Name" fullWidth />
  <TextField label="Phone number" fullWidth />
  <TextField label="Special instrucitons" fullWidth multiline />
 </Grid>
</Grid>
```